# Go applications fails and exits when running using docker-compose, but works fine with docker run command

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I am running all of these operations on a remove server that is a
**VM running Ubuntu 16.04.5 x64**.

My Go project's Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM golang:latest

ADD . $GOPATH/src/example.com/myapp
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/example.com/myapp
RUN go build

#EXPOSE 80

#ENTRYPOINT $GOPATH/src/example.com/myapp/myapp
ENTRYPOINT ./myapp
#CMD ["./myapp"]
```

When I run the docker container using `docker-compose up -d`, the Go application exits and I see this in the docker logs:

> myapp_1  | /bin/sh: 1: ./myapp: Exec format error docker_myapp_1
>   exited with code 2

If I locate the image using `docker images` and run the image like:

```
 docker run -it 75d4a95ef5ec
```

I can see that my golang applications runs just fine:

> viper environment is: development HTTP server listening on address:
>   ":3005"

When I googled for this error some people suggested compiling with some special flags but I am running this container on the same Ubuntu host so I am really confused why this isn't working using docker.

My docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  openresty:
    build: ./openresty
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - myapp
    env_file:
     - '.env'
    restart: always

  myapp:
    build: ../myapp
    volumes:
     - /home/deploy/apps/myapp:/go/src/example.com/myapp
    ports:
      - "3005:3005"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - memcached
    env_file:
      - '.env'

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
     - "/home/deploy/v/redis:/data"
    restart: always

  memcached:
    image: memcached
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    restart: always

  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - "/home/deploy/v/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file says:

```
volumes:
 - /home/deploy/apps/myapp:/go/src/example.com/myapp
```

which means your host system's source directory is mounted over, and hides, everything that the Dockerfile builds.  `./myapp` is the *host's* copy of the `myapp` executable and if something is different (maybe you have a MacOS or Windows host) that will cause this error.

This is a popular setup for interpreted languages where developers want to run their application without running a normal test-build-deploy sequence, but it doesn't really make sense for a compiled language like Go where you don't have a choice.  I'd delete this block entirely.

Comment: Thanks David!  I was up til 2am trying to figure this out.  Woke up and got it working in 5 minutes with your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Go container stops running because of this:

```
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/example.com/myapp
RUN go build

#EXPOSE 80

#ENTRYPOINT $GOPATH/src/example.com/myapp/myapp
ENTRYPOINT ./myapp
```

You are switching directories to *$GOPATH/src/example.com/myapp* where you build your app, however, your *entry point* is pointing to the wrong location.

To solve this, you either copy the app into the root directory and keep the same *ENTRYPOINT* command or you copy the application to a different location and pass the full path such as:

```
ENTRYPOINT /my/go/app/location
```